# WSO2 - Identity Server - Update username

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it supported in WSO2 to update the user username? in the console screen it is not possible, but is there a way to do it?

From API level /t/tenant1/scim2/Users/b39e1b3d-199c-4a39-ab1b-6566b3997f56:

```
{
"schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
],
"scimType": "mutability",
"detail": "Attribute userName cannot be modified.",
"status": "400"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means you can't modify the existing user's `userName` attribute as it is a unique identifier for a user account and is not meant to be modified.

If the requirement is to change the username, then that needs to be treated as a new user to the system.

You may be able to update the user's attributes of existing user (email, lastName, country and etc) only with the patch/put `scim2/Users` endpoint based on the requirements.